# JavaAssist add Annotation on class and method

Tags: annotations, javassist

I am trying to addd annotations to a class and method. I am creating the class using javaassist. I tried below code, but it does not add annotation to class and methods.

```
    ClassFile ccFile = cc.getClassFile();
    ConstPool cp = ccFile.getConstPool();
    AnnotationsAttribute attr = new AnnotationsAttribute(cp, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
    Annotation as = new Annotation("WebService", cp);
    attr.setAnnotation(as);
    ccFile.addAttribute(attr);

    attM = new AnnotationsAttribute(cp, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
    Annotation am = new Annotation("WebMethod", cp);
    attM.setAnnotation(am);

    String methodString ="...";
    CtMethod method = CtNewMethod.make(methodString, cc);
    method.getMethodInfo().addAttribute(attM);
    cc.addMethod(method);

System.out.println("cc annotation: "+cc.getAvailableAnnotations().length);
```

cc annotation: 0

Any help/pointers here is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: More details: I did not cc.writeFile(); and I see Annotation are present. But Class c = cc.toClass(), c does not have any of the annotations.

Comment: Solved. Changed attr.setAnnotation(as);  to attr.addAnnotation(as);